Why are the actions of both Buttons fired when tapping one Button?
I am using the following code to make ascending and descending buttons.
@State private var sortDirection: SortDirection = .none

List {
    HStack {
        Button("Sort ASC") {
            sortDirection = .asc
            print("ss")
        }
        Spacer()
        Button("Sort DESC") {
            sortDirection = .desc
            print("dd")
        }
    }
    
    ForEach(sortedCustomers) { customer in
        Text(customer.name)
    }
}

When I tap on any button, both button actions are fired. What is going on and how can I only fire the action of the button that was tapped?

Does this answer your question? SwiftUI - Multiple Buttons in a List row

Because your HStack is inside the list, the buttons act as one row. Therefore, you can simply extract that field outside of the List to be able to click those buttons independently
Here is the sample code how you can implement it
enum SortDirection {
    case asc
    case desc
    case none
}

struct Customer: Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sortDirection: SortDirection = .none
    
    var customers: [Customer] = [
    
        Customer(name: "John"),
        Customer(name: "Jack"),
        Customer(name: "Ryan"),
        Customer(name: "George"),
        Customer(name: "Smith"),
        Customer(name: "Dean"),
        Customer(name: "Sam")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Sort ASC") {
                    sortDirection = .asc
                    print("ss")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Sort DESC") {
                    sortDirection = .desc
                    print("dd")
                }
            }
            .padding()
           
            List {
                ForEach(customers) { customer in
                    Text(customer.name)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}


